# "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" error, app crashes when I'm fetching data from my database

Tags: java, android-studio, fatal-error

I have a list of suppliers and the idea is that when I click one it opens a more detailed page with information such as URL, specialization, country etc.

Recently, i've been trying to open suppliers to the detailed page. Every time I try to do so my application crashes and I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.labarassi/com.example.labarassi.GUI.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
```

And the error points out the following code:

```
private void getSelectedSupplier()
    {
        Intent previousIntent = getIntent();
        String parsedStringID = previousIntent.getStringExtra("id");
        selectedSupplier = SupplierPage.supplierList.get(Integer.parseInt(parsedStringID));
    }
```

If anyone has any idea as to why this is happening or what I could look for in my code it would be a great help (:

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but maybe it has something to do with `parsedStringID` number being returned not conforming to the correct index position (since indexes start at 0). Maybe try:

```
SupplierPage.supplierList.get(Integer.parseInt(parsedStringID) -1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but thank you for responding! (:

Comment: Ahh that sucks sorry i couldnt be much help, good luck with solving it :)

Comment: What is the error after trying out the suggestion by @lew ? Also, can you share the size of SupplierPage.supplierList  and the value of parsedStringID ?